# Monotouch.dialog - how to create a delegate to access an Element Value the moment it is altered

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am beginning to use the monotouch.dialog utility and would be most grateful if someone could advise me how it is possible to access instantaneous changes to a value of an element (EntryElement, FloatElement, BoolElement etc) just after it has been altered by the user. There is a delegate I could use like:-

```
        public void ViewingElementApi ()
    {
        viewingroot = CreateViewingRoot ();

        var dv = new DialogViewController (viewingroot, true)
        {
            Autorotate=true
        };
        dv.ViewDisappearing += delegate 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(EntryElement.Value);
        };

        configure.PushViewController (dv, true);                
    }
```

This snippet was courtesy of an earlier question on this. However, I am really interested in getting a value the moment it is altered by the user if this is possible.

Thanks
Gordon Pagan

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a nice enhancement - but it's not something that's presently available across all types.

E.g. for the types you mentioned:

- `EntryElement` has a `Changed` event;
- `BoolElement` has a `ValueChanged` event;
- `FloatElement` does **not** even if it uses an UISlider and it's `ValueChanged` event internally (but that's not publicly accessible outside MonoTouch.Dialog).

You best bet is to adapt MonoTouch.Dialog for your need (and later submit **pull requests** to share your work with others :-)